# Google AdMob banner ad in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, admob, navigation-drawer

I couldn't find a solid answer for that:
is it valid to put AdMob banner ad inside NavigationDrawer (the drawer shrinks a bit the size of the banner), or is it violates the policy of AdMob?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to place it there.

So first of all, why do you have an Ad in your app? - To get some revenue from displaying it of course!

Your approach isn't ideal because:

1. Not all users will click the navigation drawer button in order to see the info you display there, including the ad;
2. Unless you live in US, you are not getting paid from people just viewing your banner, you need clicks in order to get revenue.

In my opinion, just place the add at the bottom of your activity, like I did in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gqno.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to encapsulate whole code of drawer layout inside a relative layout or  constraint layout and add marginBottom of drawer layout to 50dp, and put code of banner outside it in bottom inside other layout, in this case when drawer is open, still it will be up from bottom 50dp and banner will always be visible.
thanks